# Remove button shutdown on raspberry login screen

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

How can i remove the shutdown button on raspberry login screen ?

Or can i force reboot when user click on it ? Or disable it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this :

### Disable shutdown with polkit

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/restrict-login-powermgmt.pkla

# Add this :
[Disable lightdm PowerMgmt]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.reboot;org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.suspend;org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

Comment: ...and then?  i've done this to no effect.  reboot does zip.  triple checked; all good. power off button still there.  :(